# Copy JS Function Does Not Run on Some Files While Runs Perfectly on Some

Tags: javascript

I am creating a kind of dictionary where a user enters an input value and the output in different languages/ways are showed in multiple different fields.

1 input can have multiple outputs. The output is already stored against specific input so if a specific input is present, its specified output is displayed

I am using the below code(s).

**HTML**

```html
<div id="input_container">
<input id="input_1" class="text-area-main input_mainn" type="text" placeholder="Input Goes Here" oninput="funcinput1()">
</div>
<div id="output">
<div class="text-detail"><div class="row element-inner single-element"><div class="col-md-11 col-10 position-initial heading-main"><div class="font-style-name"><span>Select My language</span></div></div><div class="col-md-1 col-2 button-main"><button class="ml-auto btn copy-btn btn_cpy col-md-1 col-12 button_copy integration-checklist__copy-button btn_copy" id="btn_copy" data-clipboard-text="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#output_1" >COPY</button></div><div class="col-md-12 col-12 position-initial text-area-outer"><div class="font-pre col-md-12 col-12 signature text-area-inner"><textarea id="output_1" class="text-area-main"></textarea></div></div></div></div>
<div class="text-detail"><div class="row element-inner single-element"><div class="col-md-11 col-10 position-initial heading-main"><div class="font-style-name"><span>Copy Eragon Ancient Language</span></div></div><div class="col-md-1 col-2 button-main"><button class="ml-auto btn copy-btn btn_cpy col-md-1 col-12 button_copy integration-checklist__copy-button btn_copy" id="btn_copy" data-clipboard-text="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#output_2" >COPY</button></div><div class="col-md-12 col-12 position-initial text-area-outer"><div class="font-pre col-md-12 col-12 signature text-area-inner"><textarea id="output_2" class="text-area-main"></textarea></div></div></div></div>
<div class="text-detail"><div class="row element-inner single-element"><div class="col-md-11 col-10 position-initial heading-main"><div class="font-style-name"><span>Pick Older Futhark Runes</span></div></div><div class="col-md-1 col-2 button-main"><button class="ml-auto btn copy-btn btn_cpy col-md-1 col-12 button_copy integration-checklist__copy-button btn_copy" id="btn_copy" data-clipboard-text="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#output_3" >COPY</button></div><div class="col-md-12 col-12 position-initial text-area-outer"><div class="font-pre col-md-12 col-12 signature text-area-inner"><textarea id="output_3" class="text-area-main"></textarea></div></div></div></div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
const translator = {
  "output_1": {
    "speak":"speek","basic":"howtobasic","ok":"k","okay":"k","yay":"yeay","yes":"yass","yeah":"yaaa","alright":"alite","owo":"ewe i nowe yoo did zat","boat":"yes a bowt","uwu":"why yoo kepe doin zat >w>","fuck":"heyy zat badd","there":"der","l":"w","enough":"enof","Z":"zed","ah":"ahe","spam":"spem","is":"iz","giant":"gient","if":"iv","you":"yoo","eat":"eet","too":"to","to":"too","much":"mach","very":"veri","fat":"fats","the":"da","coconut":"kokonut","nut":"nuut","I":"i","back":"bak","she":"se","he":"heee","hello":"henlo","one":"on","been":"bean","lick":"leek","bean":"been","la":"le","that":"zat","language":"langage","jacob":"how u gues ma neam","z":"zzz oh yoo werre takilng","yeea boiiiiiii":"yayeet boi",

  },
  "output_2":{
    "may the stars watch over you":"atra du evar\u00ednya ono varda","may good fortune rule over you":"atra estern\u00ed ono thelduin","may luck and happiness follow you, and may you be shielded from misfortune":"atra guli\u00e4 un ilian tauthr ono un atra ono wa\u00edse sk\u00f6liro fra rauthr","a":"a\u00ed","a deadly poison":"skilna bragh","a melancholy dream of great beauty":"alal\u00eba","a type of vine":"lian\u00ed","air":"vindr","all":"allr","am":"eddyr","an":"a\u00ed","and":"un","apple":"hald","are":"eru","arm":"vaupna","armor":"hernskja","arrow":"oro","as":"nen","ask":"bidja","awaken":"vakna","awry":"vrangr","back (adj)":"aptr","back (n)":"hrygr","back (n)":"bak","bad":"illr",

  },
  "output_3":{
    "speak":"speek","basic":"howtobasic","ok":"k","okay":"k","yay":"yeay","yes":"yass","yeah":"yaaa","alright":"alite","owo":"ewe i nowe yoo did zat","boat":"yes a bowt","uwu":"why yoo kepe doin zat >w>","fuck":"heyy zat badd","there":"der","l":"w","enough":"enof","Z":"zed","ah":"ahe","spam":"spem","is":"iz","giant":"gient","if":"iv","you":"yoo","eat":"eet","too":"to","to":"too","much":"mach","very":"veri","fat":"fats","the":"da","coconut":"kokonut","nut":"nuut","I":"i","back":"bak","she":"se","he":"heee","hello":"henlo","one":"on","been":"bean","lick":"leek","bean":"been","la":"le","that":"zat","language":"langage","jacob":"how u gues ma neam","z":"zzz oh yoo werre takilng","yeea boiiiiiii":"yayeet boi",
  }



};

document.querySelector("#input_1").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  for (const output of Object.keys(translator)) {
    document.querySelector(`#${output}`).value = translate(e.target, output);
  }
});

function translate(input, outputSelector) {
  const text = input.value;
  const currentTranslator = translator[outputSelector];
  const translated = replaceOnceUsingDictionary(currentTranslator, text, function(key, dictionary) {
    return dictionary[key];
  });
  return translated;
}

/*
 * @description Replaces phrases in a string, based on keys in a given dictionary.
 *               Each key is used only once, and the replacements are case-insensitive
 * @param       Object dictionary  {key: phrase, ...}
 * @param       String content
 * @param       Function replacehandler
 * @returns     Modified string
 */
function replaceOnceUsingDictionary(dictionary, content, replacehandler) {
  if (typeof replacehandler != "function") {
    // Default replacehandler function.
    replacehandler = function(key, dictionary) {
      return dictionary[key];
    }
  }

  var patterns = [], // \b is used to mark boundaries "foo" doesn't match food
    patternHash = {},
    oldkey, key, index = 0,
    output = [];
  for (key in dictionary) {
    // Case-insensitivity:
    // key = (oldkey = key).toLowerCase();
    key = (oldkey = key);
    dictionary[key] = dictionary[oldkey];

    // Sanitize the key, and push it in the list
    patterns.push('\\b(?:' + key.replace(/([[^$.|?*+(){}])/g, '\\$1') + ')\\b');

    // Add entry to hash variable, for an optimized backtracking at the next loop
    patternHash[key] = index++;
  }
  var pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi'),
    lastIndex = 0;

  // We should actually test using !== null, but for foolproofness,
  //  we also reject empty strings
  while (key = pattern.exec(content)) {
    // Case-insensitivity
    // key = key[0].toLowerCase();
    key = key[0];
    // Add to output buffer
    output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, pattern.lastIndex - key.length));
    // The next line is the actual replacement method
    output.push(replacehandler(key, dictionary));

    // Update lastIndex variable
    lastIndex = pattern.lastIndex;

    // Don't match again by removing the matched word, create new pattern
    patterns[patternHash[key]] = '^';
    pattern = new RegExp(patterns.join('|'), 'gi');

    // IMPORTANT: Update lastIndex property. Otherwise, enjoy an infinite loop
    pattern.lastIndex = lastIndex;
  }
  output.push(content.substring(lastIndex, content.length));
  return output.join('');
};
//translator code ends here


var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-btn');
  clipboard.on('success',function(e){setTooltip(e.trigger,'Copied!')});
  function setTooltip(btn,message)
{
      $("button.ml-auto.copy-btn.btn_cpy").html('COPY');
      $(btn).html('Copied!')
}
```

If you look at my code, each output textarea field has a copy button associated with it which is supposed to copy the value of the field but it does not work in this scenario. **The code stops working in some pages while it works in some other. (working code here: https://thefontworld.com/genz-talk-translator)**

Both pages have the same JS code and HTML code with the difference of input/output values entered in "output".

I am using this code for copy function:

```
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.copy-btn');
  clipboard.on('success',function(e){setTooltip(e.trigger,'Copied!')});
  function setTooltip(btn,message)
{
      $("button.ml-auto.copy-btn.btn_cpy").html('COPY');
      $(btn).html('Copied!')
}
```

One more thing I face with the same copy function is when it works, it can only work on fresh page load but, once I reload the page the copy function does not work.

I am still new to JS so learning with everything so any help in finding the cause of this copy button not working would be super useful.

P.S. The input and output valued are pre-defined in page and can have unicode, special characters and alphanumeric values

Thanks!

Hoping for a solution from pros!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This copy function should work:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button"),
  container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const id = event.target.id;
  
  const textarea = document.getElementById("textarea" + id[id.length - 1]);
  
  //just for display
  textarea.select();
  
  //copy text
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(textarea.value).then(() => {
    //text was copied successfully
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <textarea id="textarea1">some text</textarea>
  <button id="button1">copy</button>
  <textarea id="textarea2">some text</textarea>
  <button id="button2">copy</button>
  <textarea id="textarea3">some text</textarea>
  <button id="button3">copy</button>
  <textarea id="textarea4">some text</textarea>
  <button id="button4">copy</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, I have multiple buttons on front end and they should all be connected to single function instead of calling them separately and each button should only copy the contents of its respective textarea

Comment: the code does not seem to be copying content to clipboard

Comment: From MDN: "The "clipboard-write" permission of the Permissions API, is granted automatically to pages when they are in the active tab." So it should work when you implement it in your website; it worked in mine.